# Replace content of variable with Sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove some of the content of a variable in BASH. In particular I would like to remove the part following part from the variable $USER:

```
<username><![CDATA[
```

My code looks like this:

```
NUSER=`sed -e "s/\<username\>\<\!\[CDATA\[//" $USER`
```

I'm using backslashes to escape the special characters (which I'm not sure is correct), and would like to remove the mentioned part from $USER and assign the result to the variable $NUSER.

Help please. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you tried (minus some superfluous backslashes) would work if `$USER` were the name of a file that contained the value you wanted to edit. Since the value is in the variable itself, you have to pipe it to sed's stdin like so:

```
NUSER=$(echo "$USER" | sed -e 's/^<username><!\[CDATA\[//')
```

`$()` does the same as backticks, but I prefer this syntax because it's easier to nest.

Note the caveat that `echo "$USER"` causes problems if `$USER` has the value of an `echo` option (such as `-n` or `-e`). If this is a worry, take a look at Jonathan Leffer's solution with bash-specific here-strings.

Comment: I see. I am pretty new at BASH but it's really interesting. Sorry if it was a stupid question and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

The 'works everywhere' solution is suggested by [Wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27808446/15168).

The Bash-only solution uses a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) instead — that's the `<<<` notation:

```
NUSER=$(sed -e 's/^<username><!\[CDATA\[//' <<< "$USER")
```

It has the merit of avoiding a second process in the sub-shell.

Comment: Believe it or not, I was about to edit that in, albeit for a different reason: that it works even if `$USER` has the value of something that `echo` interprets as an option, such as `-n` or `-e`.  Have a +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
NUSER="${USER%%<!*}"
```

use shell variable manipulation lot faster that opening a subshell and a sed action in this case (but this is not the exact reply to your request that ask to use sed)